# Wasted overhead using using for a single Extension Method?

Tags: c#, optimization, extension-methods, using

If I have a class containing many Extension Methods, should I worry about the overhead of "using" it if I'm only using one of those Extension Methods?
If this is the case, should I perhaps put all Extension Methods in their own classes? Or perhaps there is a way to "use" a single Extension Method? (E.g., something like: `using StringMethods.RecursiveJoin;`?)

Comment: You've tagged this [optimization] - a more accurate tag would have been [premature-optimization].

Comment: What overhead are you worried about? The compilation cost is negligible and there's virtually no runtime cost.

Comment: @Marcelo: Well, that's my question, isn't it? I'm asking _if_ I should worry. It is up to you to tell me what overhead, if any! :)

Comment: @Protectorone: There are numerous quite different things that might come under the heading of "overhead": runtime overhead, load-time overhead, compile-time overhead, cognitive friction and disk space, just to name a few. It isn't obvious from your question whether you are asking about one, several, or all forms of overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It likely increases the compile time *very very* slightly. And there is no runtime overhead at all. So no reason to worry from a performance point of view.

The only thing I'd worry about is whether the design is good. Should all of those methods really be extension methods, or are some of them better off as normal static methods or even instance methods? But that question can't be answered without knowing what your extension methods do.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what is *exact* point of "overhead", but you if you are thinking about "importing" a single method, it's not possible. What you *can* do is to move/copy that method into another class, that use only you, if it will give the code more "localized" feeling (it's difficult to dedcut without seeing all project).

This will be code-layout architecture improvement, if will, but not memory, or performance.